# Changing the item orientation of a listview, datagrid, datalist or any other databound control?

Tags: asp.net

I have data that renders in a listview like this:

name address           city

Tom  200 George Street Sydney

i would like it to render like this:

name      Tom

address   200 George Street

city      sydney

Any suggestions on how I may do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. The implementations for ListView, DataList, and Repeater would be similar, but you could do something like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;margin:3px;">
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><%#Eval("Name")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><%#Eval("Address")%></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: If i have four items to bind - each row will have name: eval("Name").  I only want the column label to appear once,  at the far left of the table.  such as name: eval("Name") | eval("Name") | eval("Name") | eval("Name")